# Unable to deploy Roo web-app to localhost when offline, using SpringSource Tool Suite, 2.8.1.RELEASE

Tags: spring-mvc, deployment, localhost, spring-roo, tcserver

I'm trying to deploy (Run as->Run on Server) a basic Roo web-app (MVC + JSON + HIBERNATE) using STS 2.8.1, Windows 7 Professional/SP1, 64-bit.

Cases:

1. It won't deploy when I boot without an internet connection.
2. It will deploy when I have an internet connection, but not before I've started a Chrome session. (I don't think Chrome is the magic pill here, I just haven't had time to test any other network agent.)

Here's my log:

```
24.feb.2012 11:33:51 com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
INFO: tc Runtime property decoder using memory-based key
24.feb.2012 11:33:51 com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
INFO: tcServer Runtime property decoder has been initialized in 310 ms
24.feb.2012 11:33:52 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
24.feb.2012 11:33:52 com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.rmi.JmxSocketListener    init
INFO: Started up JMX registry on 127.0.0.1:6969 in 67 ms
24.feb.2012 11:33:52 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 934 ms
24.feb.2012 11:33:52 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
24.feb.2012 11:33:52 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: VMware vFabric tc Runtime 2.6.1.RELEASE/7.0.20.B.RELEASE
24.feb.2012 11:33:52 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor MyProject.xml from \\STS281\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.6.1.RELEASE\spring-insight-instance\conf\Catalina\localhost
24.feb.2012 11:33:52 org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:MyProject' did not find a matching property.
24.feb.2012 11:33:52    com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.ltw.TomcatWeavingInsightClassLoader start
INFO: Context [localhost|MyProject] will not be woven
24.feb.2012 11:33:52 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4660)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Perhaps *anything* that fires up the IP-stack and resolves an external host will resolve this issue. This seems a little far-fetched, particularly because I've confirmed case 2 after logging on to Windows domain (which implies communication with the PDC). I'd have to get back to you guys on that one (need to conduct some experiments tonight).

Basically, I'm wondering if anyone is familiar with my issue here? Are people able to reproduce it?

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run the Maven goal ´mvn tomcat:run´?

Comment: @bhagyas Good question. I'll try it out as soon as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a no-issue. The only way I'm able to reproduce it now is by starting the tcServer seconds after STS starts up. If I let STS load the RSS feed, I don't see this behavior.